# Command Line alternative to using QGIS GUI to save a Raster as a Rendered Image

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, msys

I have a raster image in PNG format which I can open in *QGIS but not in Windows Picture Viewer*. To do that i figured out that I have to save my raster as a ***'Rendered Image'*** from the ***'Save As'*** (option by right-clicking on it in QGIS GUI).

So great then I could now open my rendered PNG in Windows Picture Viewer.

*"Now I need a little help with as to how to do this (i.e. save the Raster as Rendered Image) without the QGIS GUI and via a Command Line"*

Comment: did you solved this task already?